# Javascript stops working with form tag

Tags: javascript

I have searched for this answer and implemented a few things I found on SO and other places to no avail. I have several javascript functions that work perfectly until I wrap the whole thing in a form. Then some functions work and others do not. My jQuery is still working.

I have tried renaming functions and ensuring I have ; at the end of all of my functions. I have used the console, and each function that doeas not work is throwing the "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" error.

Here is one of the not working HTML:

```
                <td class="tableData"><input type="text" id="teamContact" class="readonly" onfocus="teamContact();" readonly /></td>
```

And the JS to go with it:

```
 function teamContact() {
 var singleContact = (document.getElementById('contactTotalSingle').value);
 var numberLO = (document.getElementById('numberOfLO').value);
 var teamTotal = (singleContact * numberLO);
 document.getElementById('teamContact').value = (teamTotal).toFixed(2);
```

}

And a bit of the WORKING HTML:

```
                <td class="tableData"><input type="text" id="contactRate" class="contactRate"  onchange="calculateSingleContactRate();"/></td>
            <td class="tableData"><input type="text" id="contactTotalSingle" class="readonly" readonly/></td>
```

And It's working JS:

```
 function calculateSingleContactRate() {
var contactRate = (document.getElementById('contactRate').value);
var contactPercent = (contactRate / 100);
var leads = (document.getElementById('setSingle').innerHTML);
var contactTotalSingle = (contactPercent * leads);
document.getElementById('contactTotalSingle').value = (contactTotalSingle).toFixed(2);
```

}

It all works when it is not between form tags, and stops working when it is in the form tags. I know it is probably something stupid, but I cannot find it.

Let me know if you need more info or code...

Comment: A hunch: change the first function name to `teamContactFocus` and update the HTML correspondingly. (**Don't** change the "id" value of the `<input>` element - leave that "teamContact".)

Comment: That worked! The question now though is, why?

Comment: I'll add an answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers (sadly, in my opinion, but I'm not going to tilt at the windmill) create global variables (that is, `window` object properties) for each DOM element with an "id" attribute. Depending on where in the HTML you import or declare your JavaScript, that mechanism can overwrite your own explicit global symbols.

Though I seriously dislike the behavior, it's actually got a silver lining: it's a really easy way to convince people that global JavaScript variables in a browser are an even more terrible idea than global variables in other languages.

One simple way to deal with the problem is to invent a short global symbol of your own, like (for example) "A$L".  Instead of declaring your event handlers as simple global functions, declare them as properties of your own global object:

```
window.A$L = {};

// ...

A$L.teamContact = function teamContact() {
 var singleContact = (document.getElementById('contactTotalSingle').value);
 var numberLO = (document.getElementById('numberOfLO').value);
 var teamTotal = (singleContact * numberLO);
 document.getElementById('teamContact').value = (teamTotal).toFixed(2);
```

};

Now you can get to those functions almost as easily as if they were global:

```
  <td class="tableData"><input type="text" id="teamContact" class="readonly" onfocus="A$L.teamContact();" readonly /></td>
```

So long as you're careful not to introduce an element with that "id", or otherwise step on that object, you're somewhat safer. (Global variables are bad, but due to the nature of the browser environment it's difficult to *completely* avoid them.)